# Wicket - best way of adding static resources

Tags: html, wicket

In Wicket apps we could specifies the URL of resource in markup using standard HTML way like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

or we can add resource using IHeaderContributor like this:

```
@Override
public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {

    String contextPath = WebApplication.get().getServletContext().getContextPath();
    UrlResourceReference urlResourceReference = new UrlResourceReference(Url.parse(contextPath
            + "/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"));

    response.render(JavaScriptHeaderItem.forReference(urlResourceReference));

    super.renderHead(response);
}
```

In the end we have same `<script></script>` tag in html code and in second method we can only add resource to `<header>` section. So is there particular reason to use wickey way of adding resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do it because:

**TL;DR;**

In ***development*** styles and scripts are always refreshed per redeploy. In ***production*** they fetched by the clients when changes were made. Caching works correctly.

**Long explaination from [Wicket User Guide](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/6.x/guide/resources.html):**

> As you can see Wicket has automatically appended to the file name a
>   version identifier (ver-1297887542000). When Wicket runs in
>   DEVELOPMENT mode this identifier contains the timestamp in millisecond
>   indicating the last time the resource file was modified. This can be
>   useful when we are developing our application and resource files are
>   frequently modified. Appending the timestamp to the original name we
>   are sure that our browser will use always the last version of the file
>   and not an old, out of date, cached version.
>
> When instead Wicket is running in DEPLOYMENT mode, the version
>   identifier will contain the MD5 digest of the file instead of the
>   timestamp. The digest is computed only the first time the resource is
>   requested. This perfectly makes sense as static resources don't change
>   so often when our application runs into production environment and
>   when this appends the application is redeployed.

Answer (score 2):

There are probably more reasons but here is one I like:

Quote from 'Whats new in Wicket 6':

> Additionally PackageResourceReference and its specializations can
>   deliver minified version of their resource if such is available. For
>   example by using `new JavaScriptResourceReference(MyComponent.class,"my.js")` Wicket will deliver `my.js` in development mode but will
>   deliver `my.min.js` in production mode if it is available in the same
>   folder.

Off topic:
Wicket also use jQuery for à lot of things. Make sure you are not combining different verslons.